# How to use the request route parameter in Laravel 5 form request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-validation

I am new to Laravel 5 and I am trying to use the new Form Request to validate all forms in my application.

Now I am stuck at a point where I need to DELETE a resource and I created a DeleteResourceRequest for just to use the authorize method.

The problem is that I need to find what id is being requested in the route parameter but I cannot see how to get that in to the authorize method.

I can use the id in the controller method like so:

```
public function destroy($id, DeletePivotRequest $request)
{
    Resource::findOrFail($id);
}
```

But how to get this to work in the authorize method of the Form Request?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

That's very simple, just use the `route()` method. Assuming your route parameter is called `id`:

```
public function authorize(){
    $id = $this->route('id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I did dd($this->route('id')); in the authorize method. It is returning null. :(

Comment: If you're using resource routes the name of the parameter should be the name of the resource. For example `post` if you got `Route::resource('post', ...)`

Comment: Yeah I figured it out eventually by dumping he route object itself. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: `$this->route('foo)` doesn't work for me from a Laravel 5.2 Controller ("error evaluating code').  Whereas `Route::current()->getParameter('foo')` does - (see my answer.) Has something changed or do I need to load something else first?

Comment: @WilliamTurrell This question is about getting route parameters in a Form Request method (`authorize` in this case) The `route` method still exists on the request object but never has on the controller.

Answer (score 13):

You can accessing a Route parameter Value via  Illuminate\Http\Request instance

```
public function destroy($id, DeletePivotRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->route('id'))
    {
        //
    }

    Resource::findOrFail($id);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Depending on how you defined the parameter in your routes.

For my case below, it would be: `'user'` **not** `'id'`

`$id = $this->route('user');`

[image]

Comment: Had this same issue when using route model binding

Comment: @Emmanuel Opio try this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#implicit-binding

Answer (score 5):

Laravel 5.2, from within a controller:

```
use Route;

...

Route::current()->getParameter('id');
```

I've found this useful if you want to use the same controller method for more than one route with more than one URL parameter, and perhaps all parameters aren't always present or may appear in a different order...

i.e. `getParameter('id')`will give you the correct answer, regardless of `{id}`'s position in the URL.

See [Laravel Docs: Accessing the Current Route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#accessing-the-current-route)

Answer (score 1):

After testing the other solutions, seems not to work for laravel 8, but this below works

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->id
```

assuming your route is

```
Route::post('something/{id}', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for an answer and kind of found it in the comments, so wanted to clarify for others using a resource route trying to use this in a form request

as mentioned by lukas in his comment:
Given a resource controller `Route::resource('post', ...)` the parameter you can use will be named `post`

This was usefull to me but not quite complete. It appears that the parameter will be the singular version of the last part of the resource stub.

In my case, the route was defined as `$router->resource('inventory/manufacturers', 'API\Inventory\ManufacturersController');`

And the parameter available was `manufacturer` (the singular version of the last part of the stub `inventory/manufacturers`)

Answer (score 0):

you will get parameter id if you call

```
request()->route('id')
```

OR

```
$this->route('id')
```

if you're using resource routing, you need to call with the resource name

```
// eg: resource
Route::resource('users', App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class);

$this->route('user')
```

Answer (score 0):

in Terminal write

> php artisan route:list

to see what is your param name
[image]

Then use

> $this->route('sphere') to get param

Answer (score 0):

if your route is resource route then code as per below

```
// for example your route is
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');

// then

public function authorize(){
    $id = request()->post;
}
```